# cursor bug with limit in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with 5 rows, but I need to select one:

```
for row in db.foo.find({},{"_id":1}).limit(1).sort("_id",-1):print row
```

result:

```
{u'_id': 4}
```

but, when count cursor

```
flag=db.foo.find({},{"_id":1},limit=1).sort("_id",-1)
print flag.count()
```

result=5

and `flag=db.foo.find({},{"_id":1},limit=1).sort("_id",-1).count()` result: 5

anyone has idea why this happens?

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4

> > > pymongo.version
> > >       '2.5.1+'

Comment: the `count()` ignores the `limit(<num>)`, that is why the count result is 5.

Comment: but first find and later count, is equal? @AbhishekKumar

Comment: Because both the queries `db.foo.find({},{"_id":1},limit=1).sort("_id",-1).count()` and the one in which `count()` is added after is same. Even `cur=db.foo.find({},{"_id":1},limit=1), cur.sort("_id",-1), cur.count()` will give the same result. The queries are only fired, when you iterate over the cursor. So, you can decorate your cursor at any no of step (but must be before iterating). Hope it helped.

Comment: But on attaching count(), the query is fired at that moment only, as I can see from mongostat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` by default ignores `skip` and `limit` you can change this by setting the [with_limit_and_skip](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count) flag eg:

```
flag = db.foo.find({}, {"_id":1}, limit=1).sort("_id", -1)
print flag.count(with_limit_and_skip=True)
```

Comment: when I search, find only one, but when .count() the cursor the results is 5, do not count on finding, only the results...

Comment: You must do a .count(with_limit_and_skip=True) if you want it to take into account your skip and limits.  Although, if you are limiting why not cast to a list and do a len. `flag = list(db.foo.find({}, {"_id":1}, limit=1).sort("_id", -1))` and `print len(flag)`